# OBTENER EL VALOR DE UN ID CON JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Quiero guardar en un variable la respuesta que rebo de la función #result-persones, el div que tengo montado solo me muestra la respuesta de la función que es un numero, por ejemplo 278.

Y quería guardar ese numero que visualizo por pantalla en una variable para poder trabajar con ella posteriormente.

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {  
                $('#hora').on('blur', function(){

                    var data = document.getElementById("data");
                    var valor_data = data.value;

                    var persones = document.getElementById("persones");
                    var valor_persones = persones.value;
                    
                    var hora = $(this).val();       
                    var horaString = 'hora='+hora;

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "checks/check_persones.php",
                        data: {data:valor_data, hora:hora, persones:valor_persones},
                        success: function(valor_data, hora, valor_persones) {
                            $('#result-persones').fadeIn(1000).html(valor_data,hora,valor_persones);
                            var personesRecuperades = document.getElementById('result-persones').value;
                        }
                    });
                });              
            });
```

```html
<div class="disponibilitat" id="result-persones"></div>
```

Comment: Cual es el error, que no funciona, no se comprende bien tu problema, si puedes modificar tu redacción del problema mostrando los errores, en el **succes** recibes una respuesta no varias.

Comment: Ya tienes la redacción de la pregunta cambiada